# Tasker App Factory Generated app - Not reacting to variable set %CLIP

Tags: tasker

So, I created a tasker profile that monitors the %CLIP variable with the "Variable set" event, and if it's contents contain what I'm looking for, it puts up a notification. It all works in tasker, but when I export the App Factory Generated app, it doesn't provide realtime monitoring. If I launch the App Factory Generated a from the app drawer it will check the current contents of the clipboard and if it's meets the requirements it will post the notification, but it fails to monitor the clipboard and react to changes in realtime.

Do I need some sort of UI or permission for the the App Factory Generated app to run in the background? Are "Variable set" profiles not functional for App Factory Generated apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reacting to an event go for the state. Event → Variables → Variable Value → fill it.

I was not given an option to export the profile as an app so I moved the profile into a new project and exported the whole project. I disabled my profile, installed the app and whenever the clipboard contained the desired value, the app triggered the task.

**Note** that the app must be launched at least once to monitor the changes in that variable. Also, if you launch the app, it would execute the task regardless of the conditions put in place for profile.